# Request for references to literature: quantifying the complexity of cardinal arithmetic

Tags: reference-request, set-theory

Has any work been done on how to quantify the complexity of cardinal arithmetic in a given model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$? We know from Easton that $\kappa \mapsto 2^\kappa$ for regular cardinals can be anything not ruled out by König's theorem and monotonicity. In an intuitive sense, some of these functions are extremely simple (as in models where $\mathrm{GCH}$ holds), others extremely complicated (since any set can be coded in the values of $\kappa \mapsto 2^\kappa$).

It would be nice to have some sort of complexity hierarchy, or at least an analogue of recursiveness, for functions on cardinals like $\kappa \mapsto 2^\kappa$ or the $\gimel$ function. Takeuti did a sizeable amount of work in the 1960s on clarifying a notion of recursiveness for functions on ordinals taking ordinal multiplication and addition as basic operations  (*), but it's not at all clear how to extend this to cardinal arithmetic in a way that gives reasonable answers.

Any pointers to literature discussing this question would be greatly appreciated.

(*) See, e.g., "On the Recursive Functions of Ordinal Numbers", J. Math. Soc. Japan 12 (1960): 119–28, DOI 10.2969/jmsj/01220119; "A Formalization of the Theory of Ordinal Numbers", J. Symb. Log. 30 (1965): 295–317, DOI 10.2307/2269620.

Comment: What type of complexity hierarchy/analogue of recursiveness for functions on cardinals would you be hoping to find?